# Access VBA: Combobox dropdown occurring without focus?

Tags: ms-access, vba

VBA newbie here learning as I go. I have an Access form with a combo box control `Staff_Name`, which has a dropdown list of names from a query - everything about that part works absolutely fine. What I want now is for the dropdown to happen when the user puts the cursor into the box, rather than having to click on the glyph. After some research (including [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27515417/Automatically-Click-or-Dropdown-a-Listbox-in-Access.html) and switching the control type from listbox to combobox) I tried:

```
Private Sub Staff_Name_GotFocus()
    Staff_Name.Dropdown
End Sub
```

The problem is that the dropdown happens when the form opens instead of waiting for me to put the cursor into the box. In conjunction I tried setting the focus on a different control in both the `OnLoad` and `OnOpen` events and intercept the focus, but it didn't have any effect on the outcome. I also tried using the `OnClick` event instead, but then the dropdown action didn't happen at all, which is especially strange.

How do I make the dropdown action occur when someone puts their cursor into the `Staff_Name` combobox? I'm betting I'm misunderstanding what "focus" is.

EDIT: After posting I [found an alternative solution](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?760875-RESOLVED-ComboBox-DropDown-List-Event-on-Click) using `MouseDown` that was successful. Some commenters were unable to replicate my original problem, which still leaves me curious what happened...

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. My combobox Got_Focus works just fine, dropdown activates when I tab or click into.

Comment: I can't duplicate this behavior,  When I add this code to the GotFocus event, it doesn't execute at startup, nor can I get the GotFocus event to execute at startup even if I manually set the focus to the control. Did you perhaps write Staff_Name.Dropdown in another event?

Comment: What is the code you have in Form Open event? How many controls do you have on your form - and is your combobox the first one (Tab Order = 0)? That might generate the Focus if the form is going to the first control on the form.

Comment: I fixed it by using the MouseDown event instead of GotFocus. @Jeffrey This is the only place I'm trying to do this.

Comment: @dbmitch the code in the FormOpen event is: Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer) Me.Move 0, 0 DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.name, acNewRec End Sub

There are nine controls on the form, with this one being the sixth. I had thought something similar (that it might be focusing on `Staff_Name` first (for any reason) which is why I tried to make it focus elsewhere first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create empty form, place textbox, set "Tab Index" for that textbox to 0 (by default it should be 0 already, but just in case...), place combobobox, set vba "On got focus" to Combo1.Dropdown. When form load textbox with "Tab Index" 0 will get focus first, when you tab next "Tab Index" gets focus and your dropdown should execute. I use empty textbox with 0 heigh, width, left and top, to open my forms without having highlight on any of the textboxes.